# Gsteamer conflicting declaration in opencv in Yocto build

Tags: opencv, compilation, gstreamer, yocto

I am building Yocto 2.5(Sumo) with Gstreamer 1.14 and OpenCV 3.4.5

I am getting this error while compiling Gstreamer:

```
build_xwayland_mq/tmp/work/aarch64-mx8m-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/1.14.4.imx-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h:445:21: error: conflicting declaration of C function 'CvMoments cvMoments(const cv::Moments&)'
 CV_INLINE CvMoments cvMoments(const cv::Moments& m)
```

same error in imgproc_c.h:360:13

I saw someone solved this by building with OpenCV 4 instead, but we need OpenCV 3.4.5 for our own project.

Anyone know how to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

too long for comment..

I did just quick search, found this:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/meta-freescale/2019-March/023888.html

There is some problem in includes .. I guess in mentioned hpp files there are some types that are not declared in that imgproc_c.h for 3.4, but already are moved there for opencv 4 (just my guess).
You just need to add those hpp on all places (in gst plugins bad) where you find include for `imgproc_c.h`.

Take inspiration from this.. or maybe it itself will solve your issue:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-freescale/tree/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/0001-opencv-fix-build-for-opencv-3-4-2.patch?h=thud
The patch is for yocto thud.. but perhaps it does not matter for GStreamer.
In worst case you will have to backport it or make your own patch for sumo.

Or if you can try update to thud (should be small difference) or newer and check if it persists.